# Passing variable double[]

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
double[] value1 = {1010,2010,3010,4010,5010};
double[] value2 = {1020,2020,3020,4020,5020};
}
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
double begin = Math.Round(value1.Min() / 100d, 0) * 100;
double end = Math.Round(value1.Max() / 100d, 0) * 100;
//then some more math happens using value1 and value1
}
```

How do I declare the double[] so that it can pass it between the event hander, so basically btn1_Click assign a some values to value1 and value2 and btn2_click uses value1 and value2 for some calculations

Comment: Declare it outside of the method as field in the same class.

Comment: You can't pass local variables between methods. Upgrade them to class variables.

Comment: It's called an array. Please read the [MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) and maybe a beginner's C# book.

Comment: `double [] value1 = { 1010, 2010, 3010, 4010, 5010 };`

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "pass it along?" Are you trying to share the data between event handlers? Trying to convert two doubles into an array? Trying to move it between pages/forms/classes? We'll need a lot more information before we can answer this question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What happens when you compile your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the two double values (arrays) as variables in the class should allow you to make use of them everywhere in the code for that class.

```
class X
{
    double[] value1;
    double[] value2;

    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] val1 = {...};
        value1 = val1;
        double[] val2 = {...};
        value2 = val2;
    }
}
```

And so on.